# Find in Reference is not working

Tags: processing

I select the function name (in this case fill()) and choose Find in Reference from the menu and I get the error message

> Could not open the URL
>
> file:/C:Users/userB/Desktop/processing-2.0b7/modes/java/reference/fill.html

But the file is there in the specified location:

[image]

Does anyone know why the URL is not opening?

---

**Edit**

I just noticed that the file has an underscore at the end: `fill_.html`. Can this be the reason?

**Edit 2**

The files without the underscore are opening. Do you know why some files have underscores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Processing's issue list [#1456](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=1456), this is a known issue in the current beta version 2.0b7. Issue [#1474](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=1474) mentions the underscore issue, but it is merged into issue #1456. So I expect it will get fixed in upcoming releases.

Meanwhile, you may want to try the stable release, currently version 1.5.1.

---

**Edit**: As the comment suggests, a temporary workaround would be to remove the trailing underscore from each .html file in `inmodes\java\reference`.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. Do I need to uninstall the version I have and install 1.5.1?

Comment: What happens if I remove the underscores and rename the files?

Comment: You should be able to have multiple versions of processing. Removing the underscores should fix it for you, as a solution until it's fixed in a future release.